# Dynamic/composite column in DataDog

Tags: datadog

I calculate statistics over log entries in DataDog.
One of my columns is URI with different URIs and some of them are "ke1/ID/key2/ID", where key1 and key2 are constant values but ID values are different.
When I group by URI column, I have different entries for URIs with different IDs. But for me they mean the same thing.

What is a possible way to group by URI column but treat URIs with different IDs as one?

I thought of adding dynamic column that gives a single value for URIs with different IDs and group by it, but I don't see how to do that in DataDog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New processor can be used to extract new column https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-categorize-logs/